# Microsoft Azure Storage AzCopy : error parsing the argument "copy"

Tags: azure, azcopy

I'm trying to dowload some data from a blob for which I have a SaS key with AzCopy.

**My code :**

```
azcopy copy "my/path/testMindee/fileData.txt" "https...blob.core.windows.net/90138?sv=mykey&sp=rl"
```

**The error :**
*The syntax of the command is incorrect. Error parsing the argument "copy" : parameter is required.*
[A screenshot of my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJOEf.png)

---

I've tried after that :

**My code :**

```
azcopy cp "https...blob.core.windows.net/90138/DBxxx/file.csv?sv=mykey&sp=rl" "my/path/testMindee/fileData.txt" --recursive
```

**The error :**
*The syntax of the command is incorrect. Error parsing the argument "copy" : parameter is required.*

[My second try](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9vye.png)

Both still give me the error : *The syntax of the command is incorrect. Error parsing the argument "cp": parameter name is required.*

Thank you in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please avoid posting code as images. Instead mask/obfuscate the sensitive information (account name in your case) when posting code. Please edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Regarding formatted text vs images of text: This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is important.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Sorry for that I'm new on SO. I've edited my question adding my code on quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you image you have code like this:

```
azcopy copy "path/to/local/file" "path/to/storageacc/blob"
```

The error message says: "Error parsing the argument copy".
Basically you need to do **azcopy cp** instead of azcopy copy

You want to downlaod a file from a storageaccount with a sas token

> I'm trying to get some data **from a blob** for which I have a SaS key with AzCopy

From the [ms azcopy copy documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-ref-azcopy-copy?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#examples):

> Download a single file by using a SAS token:

```
azcopy cp "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]" "/path/to/file.txt"
```

In case you want to uplaod a file

```
azcopy cp "/path/to/file.txt"> "https://[account].blob.core.windows.net/[container]/[path/to/blob]?[SAS]"
```

So when you want to download **from** a storage account you need to put the remote location first and the path where the fiel shoudl be stored second. Also the azcopy command is followed by **cp** not copy.

Kind regards

Comment: Hello thanks a lot for your answer. I'm going to edit my question to include the chances that I've made

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the latest version of AzCopy? The documentation you are following is for AzCopy 10.

I had the same error as you, and suddenly found out I'm using AzCopy version 8.1, which has a completely different way of sending in parameters.

Example usage of AzCopy 8.1:

`AzCopy /Source:<source> /Dest:<destination> [options]`